# Join of Two Tables Not Working on Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, nullreferenceexception

I have a report page that I am trying to create on a Razor page app and I cannot get it to work. I have a similar working app and cannot see where I am doing anything differently, but must be missing something obvious.

Here is the view in question:

```
@page
@model RabiesShotTracker.Pages.Reports.UnpaidBills.IndexModel

<div id="UnpaidBillsIndex" class="container p-3">
    <div class="row pt-4">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Unpaid Bills</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <form asp-page="./Index" method="post">
        <div id="UnpaidBillsReport" class="row pt-4">
            <div class="col-25">
                <h2 class="text-primary" align="center">Public Health</h2>
                <h3 class="text-primary" align="center">Rabies Shots Unpaid Bills</h3>
            </div>
                <table id="DataTable" class="table table-bordered" style="width:75%" align="center">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style ="text-align: center">
                                Incident No
                            </th>
                            <th style="text-align: center">
                                Patient Name
                            </th>
                            <th style="text-align: center">
                                Date of Birth
                            </th>
                            <th style="text-align: center">
                                Exposure Date
                            </th>
                            <th style="text-align: center">
                                Date Shot Scheduled
                            </th>
                            <th style="text-align: center">
                                Date Shot Received
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Client.Shots.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 15%">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <input asp-for="Client.Shots[i].IncidentNo" type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 25%">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <input asp-for="Client.FullName" type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 15%">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <input asp-for="Client.Birthdate" type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 15%">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <input asp-for="Client.ExposureDate" type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 15%">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <input asp-for="Client.Shots[i].ShotSchedDate" type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 15%">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <input asp-for="Client.Shots[i].ShotRecdDate" type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is the .cs behind it:

```
using RabiesShotTracker.Data;
using RabiesShotTracker.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace RabiesShotTracker.Pages.Reports.UnpaidBills
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public Client Client { get; set; }
        public Shot Shot { get; set; }


        public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public void OnGet(int Id)
        {
            Client = _db.Client
                    .Include(client => client.Shots).FirstOrDefault(client => client.ClientId == Id);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the relevant portion of the Client model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace RabiesShotTracker.Model
{
    public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Client Id")]
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        public List<Shot>? Shots { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Client No (###)")]
        public string? ClientNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Incident No")]
        public string? IncidentNo { get; set; }
```

And here is the relevant portion of the Shot model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace RabiesShotTracker.Model
{
    public class Shot
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int ShotId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        public Client? Client { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Incident No")]
        public string? IncidentNo { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Client No")]
        public string? ClientNo { get; set; }
```

When I run the app, I am getting a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at the line:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Client.Shots.Count; i++)
```

Both tables (Client and Shot) have values in them, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. I have been staring at this for way too long.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint on the OnGet() method do you have shots?

Comment: If I am doing it correctly, both Client and Shot return null.

Comment: So you probably shouldn't be getting null ... how are you passing in an Id for the "client"?

Comment: Could you please share how is your `ApplicationDbContext ` looks like? Have you checked in your database if the foreign key has been generated in the table column? In addition, have you tried adding foreign key reference on clientId property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both tables (Client and Shot) have values in them, so I am not sure
> what I am doing wrong? Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Well, first of all your Shot table design or model defination has violated the [3NF database normaliation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description#third-normal-form) because, by Client ID you can access all the entities from shot table therefore, IncidentNo  and ClientNo  are just repetation of Client table.

However, your table relationship shouldn't have the issue for getting data by joining them with ClientId. I have investigated along with your code snippet and tried to insert few manual data and it seems working as expected.

What, I am assuming please, check your search key which is the Id you are passing in your `OnGet(int Id)` method.

Apart from that, you should also check your ApplicationDbContext defination and  if that has created your database table schema accordingly.

On top of that, please check your ClientId if that has correct maching on Shot table.

I have tried the same way you did, and I have executed migration command and it has created database table as following:

Database Table After Migration:

[image]

Appsetting.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\ProjectModels;Database=RazorPageTableJoinDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
```

Db Context Class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Shot> Shots { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            

        }
    }
```

Program.cs Class:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
```

Razor Page.cs:

```
public class ForeignKeyTableJoinModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public Client Client { get; set; }
        public Shot Shot { get; set; }


        public ForeignKeyTableJoinModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            var Id = 1;
            
            Client = _db.Clients
                    .Include(client => client.Shots).FirstOrDefault(client => client.ClientId == Id);
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:**  Make sure, you have correct data in regards of your given ClientId, and in database table they have correct relation. Also, you are sending query into correct database in your appsetting.json connection string.

Comment: When I take away the 'int Id' in the public void OnGet(int Id) and add the var = 1 as you did, the report will work. If I change it back to public void OnGet(int Id) running the report  gives me the null exception error. App Db Context is fine. FK is missing in database table though. What is the proper syntax for adding it via the Shot Model? I must be getting it wrong. I am trying [ForeignKey("Client.ClientId")].

Comment: Yeah you should get null reference exception if you want to filter while loading the view of Clients and Slots list with `OnGet(int Id)` because on loading you will not have any specific ID rather the full list and this  `OnGet(int Id)` parameter will always be null onload. You must send the specific Id from your view to filter query in your razor.cs file.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you. In this particular instance, I what I am looking for is all of the clients that have not paid for their shot. The field in question is in the Shot model: Shot.ShotPaidDate. How would I change my statement to look for all clients who did NOT have a paid date? I'm just not sure of the syntax.

Comment: Items that I need on the report are from BOTH the Client model and the Shot model.

Comment: What all you need is, a search box, take the value from it , or it can be a dropdown based on your search criteria, take the input and populate the view again. At this question, we actually figure out why your `"Join of Two Tables Not Working on Razor Page"` not working. So, it would be great, if you could post new question for that, so that question would keep specific problem oriented and if I updated this question along with your current requirement, this answer would be very long.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. The reason it actually wasn't working was my looking for multiple results and having code written to only request one.

Comment: No worries, if you have any further concern feel free to post new question, I will try assisting you.